# NGINX: Block all external IPs except the server IP where ReactJS is hosted?

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, reverse-proxy

Can anyone help how to configure nginx so it only accepts the server IP where ReactJS is hosted?
Ive tried many options to no avail. I always see ReactJS is using the client IP where the user is currently browsing (because of I guess of its client-based nature). Unfortunately, I need to block all other request to protect my Django rest api from external requests. My Django app is having this nginx reverse proxy by the way. How do you guys do this?

Comment: Are you talking about CORS configuration?

Comment: @abkdTECH could you provide your `nginx` config? You can do it with `nginx -T`.

Comment: hi @allexiusw, yeah this would have been a CORS config but I have an nginx reverse proxy that serves in front of my django backend and I thought thats should where the blcoking of other IPs should come from.

Comment: Hi @user973254, here is my nginx config.. I made no blockings at the moment.

`server {
    listen 80;
        server_name api.serverwebsite.com;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass ecommerce-backend:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }


}`

Comment: Can you provide your CORS configuration defined in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you seriously misunderstood how your app works. Unless you are doing something really, really weird, it generally works like this:

- The user's browser (the client) receives the ReactJS code from the server hosting it
- The ReactJS code is executed in the user's browser
- All requests for your REST API will originate from the user's browser executing the ReactJS code, i.e. coming from the client machine, not from the server hosting the ReactJS code
- The server hosting the ReactJS code merely returns the ReactJS code to client, and doesn't even interact with the server hosting Django REST API

Thus, what you are attempting to do is misguided and in fact will just restrict your users.

As a side note, you may use several complicated techniques to be somewhat sure that the API requests *do* come from a browser executing your ReactJS code (i.e. a legitimate use of your API) rather than other tools, but that's far from a guarantee and in most cases serves no practical purpose anyway.

Comment: This actually seriously doesnt answer my question.. I actually understand that ReactJS works on the client side. That is a known knowledge. What I was just actually asking is that, could there be a way of knowing exactly the host server of ReactJS? if you or anyone thinks there is, then that would be great and I would be interested to know.. if its a no for you then maybe the others might have created some creative ways or tweaks to do it..